# Распараллеливание циклов в C

Tags: c, многопоточность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно распараллелить выполнение подобного цикла на C.

```
for(int i = 0; i < X; i++)  
{
    for(int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < Z; k++) 
        {
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 27; i2++)  
            {
                if (count < 27) 
                {
                    count++;
                    x_vect.push_back(x_mas[i2]);
                    y_vect.push_back(y_mas[i2]);
                    z_vect.push_back(z_mas[i2]);
                }
                else
                {
                    x_vect.push_back(i*a + 2*a1 + x_mas[i2]);
                    y_vect.push_back(j*b + 2*b1 + y_mas[i2]);
                    z_vect.push_back(k*c + 2*c1 + z_mas[i2]);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проводится множество итераций и хотелось бы, как можно проще сгенерировать код для загрузки обоих ядер. Используется MS Visual Studio 2010 и Intel C++ Compiler. Процессор - Core2Duo. После включения оптимизации, в том числе SSE3, скорость выросла почти в 12 раз. Но хотелось бы организовать многопоточность. На включение QParallel ругается.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP

Comment: @Вадим Владимиров, извини за оффтоп, где скачать intel c++ compiler?

Comment: Например, [прямо отсюда](http://software.intel.com/ru-ru/intel-parallel-studio-xe).

Answer (score 5):

Алгоритм сводится к последовательному заполнению массива данными. Такая задача легко распараллеливается на два ядра. Нужно разбить внешний цикл на два: первый от 0 до X/2 - 1, а второй от X/2 до X - 1. И запустить на выполнение в разных потоках.

Кроме того, поскольку размеры вектора известны заранее, нет смысла использовать собственно вектор, можно взять плоский массив float и писать прямо в него по индексу (`x[n++]`) или по указателю (`*x++`).

Еще можно ускорить алгоритм, если убрать избыточную вложенность, то есть вместо трех вложенных циклов сделать один, а уже внутри считать индексы, по которым обращаться к массиву.

Comment: С фразой про вектор согласиться не могу, поскольку в векторе прекрасно можно заранее выделить память и использовать его как обычный динамический массив с прямой индексацией.

Comment: + предложение от IAZ (11 Мар 15:48)

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к ответу @jmem можно заметить, что в самом внутреннем цикле (по i2) для count >= 27 в выражениях:

```
x_vect.push_back(i*a + 2*a1 + x_mas[i2]);
y_vect.push_back(j*b + 2*b1 + y_mas[i2]);
z_vect.push_back(k*c + 2*c1 + z_mas[i2]);

i*a + 2*a1  j*b + 2*b1 и k*c + 2*c1
```

можно вычислять во внешних циклах.

Comment: В принципе да, спасибо за совет!

Comment: Еще одно дополнение. Цикл по i2 можно вообще убрать, размножив последовательности ...push_back(... ) 27 раз, т.е вместо i2 писать 0 1 ... 26.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже было сказано dmitry_'eм, для таких случаев существует прекрасная библиотека [OpenMP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), но для данной задачи, если я ее правильно понял, распараллеливание не нужно. Первая часть кода выполнится первые 27 раз, вторая остальные. Тут нет параллельности, здесь последовательное выполнение. Если вы хотите оптимизировать именно этот алгоритм, вынесите следующий код в отельный цикл, идущий перед данным.

```
x_vect.push_back(x_mas[i2]);
y_vect.push_back(y_mas[i2]);
z_vect.push_back(z_mas[i2]);
++count;
```

Answer (score 2):

В данной ситуации, без иных оптимизирующих изменений в коде, можно, как уже было написано, применить OpenMP. Перед циклом поставить следующую прагму:

```
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate (a, b, c, a1, b1, c1) shared (x_mas, y_mas, z_mas)
```

Ну и подключить соответствующие библиотеки.

Можно вручную создать два потока.

Но только учтите, что создание потоков - довольно дорогая процедура, и имеет смысл ее применять либо когда число итераций очень велико (сотни тысяч, по меньшей мере), либо внутри итераций проводятся продолжительные расчеты.

Comment: shared vector в openmp?! Это что за магия такая?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, что не так?